# jQuery $.get request (with public readonly UN and PW) to cloudant returning 401?

Tags: jquery, cloudant

I'm building a web application that needs to be able to rapidly query a couchdb database for data for real-time analysis on a web page. I have my data stored and ready in the database, however, when I try to request a view via jQuery on my web app it gets 401'd. Here is the code:

```
var searchGet = function(query) {
    $.get("http://username:password@myURL.cloudant.com/myDB/_design/myView/_view/myView?reduce=false&startkey=%22" + query,
    function(data) {

        // do some function

    });
};
```

I can get to the same view just fine by copying and pasting the link in the URL bar and can also access the same exact view just fine via R. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you're getting a 401 ***Unauthorized*** error? How about checking the server logs to see why the server refuses the connection as not being authorized.

Comment: Also, chain on a `fail()` to the ajax request, and check the console (F12) for errors, here's how -> https://jsfiddle.net/597d3bLj/

Comment: thank you! I'll look into this.